# CDNSaver - never look for a CDN link twice

Tags: script, editing

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: CDNSaver-Trailer-SpectricSO]

### About

Stack Snippets provides a great shortcut for popular library CDN links via the dropdowns on the left sidebar. However, it's uncustomizable, and when it comes to unsupported libraries, searching for their CDN links can be a pain.

CDNSaver allows you to save library CDN links by adding a subwidget to the left sidebar that behaves just like the other shortcut dropdowns. You'll never have to look for a CDN link twice.

---

#### Manual

To add a library, click the 'Add library' button. In the prompt, enter the name of the library and the URL **separated by a space**.

For example, if the library was Bootstrap, you would enter:

```
Bootstrap https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

<sup>The name cannot contain a space for this reason</sup>

To delete a library from the list, select it from the dropdown and click 'Delete'.

---

#### Download

| Version | Minified | Unminified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Version 1.0](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/CDNSaver/v1.0) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CDNSaver/v1.0/script.min.user.js) | [link](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/CDNSaver/v1.0/script.user.js) |

#### Additional Information

| #### License | #### Suggestions/Issues |
| --- | --- |
| [MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE) | Suggestions and issues should be raised as an answer in this post |

#### changelog

- ###### version 1.1 (planned)

  - bulk upload (for libraries like Bootstrap that have lots of dependencies), seperated URLs by commas

---

Languages/libraries used: [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)